# sylow p-subgroups of S3, S4 and S5

Tags: group-theory

I want to find the sylow p-subgroups of S3, S4 and S5, but I don´t understand the iterated wreath products, can I help me?

Comment: start to factorise 6, 24, 120 into prime numbers

Comment: |s3|=2*3      |s4|=2^3*3      |s5|=2^3*3*5

Comment: You don't need to know about iterated wreath products to solve this.  Start with $S_3$, which is very easy.

Comment: In S3: there are 3 sylow 2-subgroups and 1 sylow 3-subgroup. In S4: there are 3 sylow 2-supgroup and 2 sylow 3-subgroup. In S5: 5 sylow 2-subgroups, 4 sylow 3-subgroups and 6 sylow 5-subgroups. With the iterated wreath products i can find all of them, but i don't understand.

Comment: somebody can explain me? please

Answer (score 2):

If $P,Q$ are both $p$ sylow subgroups of a group $G$ then there
is $g\in G$ s.t
$$
P=g^{-1}Qg
$$

thus it is enough to find one $p$-sylow subgroup and take all conjugates
of that subgroup to get all the others